# How to find a locations inside a Polygon with multiple data points and inside a circle with centroid lat/long, radius using uber h3-js?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, maps, uber-api, h3

I am working on a bike-sharing application where I have the following requirements.

1. **Show all bikes near the user locations in a certain radius.**

   *For this I came with an approach where get all indexes of bike
   locations on a specific resolution and get all the indexes from the user location
   with a radius using **kRing*** function and then find all the bike locations which are
   inside kRing indexes.

```
const res = 8;
//get hexagon index of all locations
const lookupMap = bike_locations.reduce((map, bike) => {
    const {latitude, longitude} = bike;
    const h3Index = h3.geoToH3(latitude, longitude, res);
    if (!map[h3Index]) map[h3Index] = [];
    map[h3Index].push(bike.id);
    return map;
}, {});

//hexagon index of user location
const origin = h3.geoToH3(user_lat, user_logn, res);
const radius = Math.floor(distance_in_km / (h3.edgeLength(res, h3.UNITS.km) * 2));
const lookupIndexes = h3.kRing(origin, radius);

// Find all points of bikes in those indexes
const results = lookupIndexes.reduce(
    (output, h3Index) => [...output, ...(lookupMap[h3Index] || [])], 
    []);
```

2. I have a big circle with centre lat/long, the radius of the circle in km and these big circle divided into multiple polygons with data points.

   **How to get all the bikes that are outside the city boundary (i.e big circle)?**

   **How to get in which polygon how many bikes are existing and how to get in which polygon a given bike location present using polyfill?**
3. How to display all the bike locations, polygons, big circle and filled with hexagons on a map? here I am using MapmyIndia.

How can I implement the above requirements using Uber H3-js and my solution for the point is correct or any better solution is there for the same?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of questions here, and I'm not sure I understand them all, but here's my attempt:

**K-ring lookup**

The k-ring based radius lookup seems like a reasonable solution (looks like it's based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062117/380487)), particularly if the bike lookup map can be calculated once rather than every time you need to perform the lookup.

**Bikes not in circle**

Getting all the bikes not in the circle works in a similar way. If you need the circle to be more circular than a k-ring, you'd need to calculate the set of hexes within the circle - there isn't an H3 function for this, but a reasonable approach might look like:

1. Calculate a k-ring of cells that covers the circle
2. Check the haversine distance from each cell center to the circle center
3. If `distance <= radius` add the cell to the circle set

Now you have a set of cells representing the circle, filter out all bikes whose cells are in that set. The remaining bikes are outside the circle.

**Bikes in polygons**

To take a set of polygons and use it for lookup, you'll need a reverse index (cell => polygon). You can create it like this (untested):

```
const lookup = {};
for (const poly of polygons) {
  for (const cell of h3.polyfill(poly, res)) {
    lookup[cell] = polygon; // or polygon id, or whatever
  } 
}
```

Now you can use the index to easily lookup the polygon for a particular bike. To count the bikes in a polygon, you can either loop through all the bikes and count which ones are inside, or loop through all the cells in the polygon and determine which ones have a bike - these are both `O(n)`, so the better option just depends on which `n` is smaller, bikes or cells.